# Вода и водить

Tags: омонимы, однокоренные-слова

Я могу сейчас ошибаться - поправьте, если что. "Вода" и "водить" - это фактически омонимы, смысловой связи между ними нет. Но и у того, и у другого слова корень "вод". То же самое (если это неудачный пример) можно сказать о других омонимах.
И вот у меня вопрос специалистам: можно ли считать эти слова однокоренными? То есть, если корни одинаковые, но смысл у них разный.
Простите, если вопрос глупый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя их считать однокоренными, если они не восходят к одному корню. "Одинаковые корни" – это просто случайное совпадение. Не так уж много звуков в языке, а корни длинными не бывают – вот и совпали.

Answer (score 0):

А во мне думается, это не совпадение. Раньше дороги были по воде, и суда именно водили.